Story about a time traveler who is accused of counterfeiting when attempting to spend contemporary currency in the past
I’m sorry I don’t remember any more details, but I’m looking for a time travel story, probably a book. I was exposed to it in the 1990s. All I can remember is that there was a protagonist (possibly a minor child) who was able to time travel. They brought contemporary currency (likely US$ paper money) to the past with them, but when they tried to use it they were accused of counterfeiting it because the series date was obviously in the future.

In roughly which year did you read this?

The Journeyman TV show apparently had this as a plot point, but it was not a child.

I think this has been told several times... I have vague recollections of someone accused of passing counterfeit coins (Wrong date) but also of someone passing a coin with someone who is alive. (For instance a Kennedy 50¢ Coin, while he was alive, or maybe not even president yet) I think I remember another story with someone getting in trouble for passing paper bills from the future too.

I agree with @NJohnny this features in a number of stories.

@LogicDictates likely 1994-1999, almost certainly in the 1990s! thanks for reminding me to provide that info.

The narrator of Jack Finney's "The Third Level" tried to spend 1950s US money in 1894, but he was an adult not a child, and it's a short story not a book.

Sounds like a very common trope,  probably need more details to zoom in on this.

Hmm, now that I am thinking on it, I believe the Kennedy 50¢ coin story I am sure it was  one of the twilight zone type shows. Guy goes back in time does something that changes time around Kennedy, Proves it to Kennedy by showing him the coin which was a family heirloom, and in the end takes Kennedy's place in the car in Dallas, while Kennedy goes forward to his time.

NJohnny:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profile_in_Silver
